# OctoberCMS: online website outputs random page scripts in a <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, server, octobercms

I just put an OctoberCMS website online and wierdly enough,sometimes on chrome/firefox/safari (tested browsers) the page outputs random script o style included in the page in a pre tag.

I add all the scripts and styles from a specific page with the `$this->addCss('index.css');` function, and the generic ones like so: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{'assets/js/app.js'|theme }}"></script>` or `<link href="{{'assets/css/index.min.css'|theme }}" rel="stylesheet">`.

Am I doing something wrong? In my dev server works great.

Home HTML content:

```html
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">html,body{padding:0;margin:0}*{box-sizing:border-box}a{text-decoration:none}figure{margin:0}...</pre></body></html>
```

[Home Page screenshot in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FaFD.png)